# Angular Gridster2 how to export all items to a PDF?

Tags: angular, html-to-pdf, angular-gridster2

We have a dashboard in angular application which is made in gridster2.
It contains several widgets, we wants that all the widgets should get exported to a pdf in A4 size.
what libraries can help us do that thing.

We have tried
convas2html which is not production ready, and get stuck when page is long.

Answer (score 0):

```ts
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';  

@ViewChild('gridStack') gridStack!: ElementRef;

downloadAsPDF(): void {
    const dashboard = this.gridStack.nativeElement;
    const dashboardHeight = dashboard.clientHeight;
    const dashboardWidth = dashboard.clientWidth;
    const options = {
        background: 'white',
        width: dashboardWidth,
        height: dashboardHeight,
    };
    domtoimage.toPng(dashboard, options).then((imgData: any) => {
        const doc = new jsPDF(
            dashboardWidth > dashboardHeight ? 'l' : 'p',
            'mm',
            [dashboardWidth, dashboardHeight]
        );
        const imgProps = doc.getImageProperties(imgData);
        const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
        const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;

        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
        doc.save(this.dashboard.name);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).